# rails check if page is translated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, translation

I am writing a helper for our app that will return if the page is not in english. At first this was my check:

```
!params[:lang].nil? || !cookies[:lang].nil? || !session[:lang].nil? || !session[:locale] || !params[:locale]
```

(i looked at params, cookies, and sessions) if any of them wasn't nil, then I'd immediately conclude that the user clicked on our translate link(which introduces the params[:lang] and add it to the session and cookie.

One thing I forgot is that if the user switched back to "en", then it would still be !nil. Is there a quick and easy way/call of checking if the page isn't in English? Or am i stuck with doing a lot of ifs for each params, cookies and sessions to check if they exist AND if they are in english?

Comment: The resulting code isn't any more complicated, just return !(params[:lang] == "en" && ... && params[:local] == "en")

Comment: well i just thought i could do with less ifs if there was a rails method for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a few code snippets of what I did and some from refactormycode:

http://refactormycode.com/codes/1387-too-many-ifs-and-ands

```
def is_english?
  [params, cookies, session].each do |store|
    return (store[:lang].andand.to_s == "en" || store[:locale].andand.to_s == "eng")
  end

  false
end
```

Hope it helps anyone!